# Kivy GUI freezes when sending repeated commands

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following code in which I am trying to send time to an Arduino to be displayed on an OLED. the Arduino side works well, if commands are sent individually it will display. However, I want the time to be updated every second. With some tweaking I am able to get it to update ever 2 seconds or so, with sometimes showing two times at once. I tried using threading but I'm not sure if its correct or not.
Here is the python script:

```
    import serial
    import kivy
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import time
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    import threading
    
    ard_connected = False
    
    try:
        ard = serial.Serial(
        port='COM10',
        baudrate = 9600
        )
        ard.flush()
        ard_connected = True
    except:
        print("Arduino Not Connected")
    
    Builder.load_file('Layout.kv')
    
    
    class GUILayout(Widget):
        def ShowTime(self, state):
            threading.Timer(1, self.ShowTime).start()
            now = datetime.now()
            a = timedelta(seconds=1)
            while state == 'down':
                if (ard_connected):
                    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                    ard.write(current_time.encode())
                    ard.flush()
                    now += a
    
            if (ard_connected):
                ard.write(" ".encode())
                ard.flush()
    
    class GUI(App):
        def build(self):
            updateClock = GUILayout()
            Clock.schedule_interval(updateClock.ShowTime, 0.5)
            return updateClock
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        GUI().run()
```

and the .kv file:

```
    <GUILayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
            
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
    
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Time"
                on_state: root.ShowTime(self.state)
                backgrund_normal: ""
                background_color: (150/255,150/255,150/255,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many things starting the `ShowTime()` method:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(updateClock.ShowTime, 0.5)
```

and

```
on_state: root.ShowTime(self.state)
```

and

```
threading.Timer(1, self.ShowTime).start()
```

And each of those has the possibility to start an infinite loop (`while state == 'down':`), since the `state` variable that is passed into `ShowTime()` will never change. The loop started by clicking on the `ToggleButton` will run in the main thread, freezing your GUI.

I believe a better approach would be to just start/stop the `ShowTime()` method at one location. perhaps using the `ToggleButton`.

Try changing the `kv` to accomplish that:

```
        ToggleButton:
            text: "Time"
            on_state: root.startShowTime(self.state) if self.state == 'down' else root.stopShowTime()
            backgrund_normal: ""
            background_color: (150/255,150/255,150/255,1)
```

and add/change `GUILayout` and `GUI` methods to support that:

```
class GUILayout(Widget):
    def startShowTime(self, state):
        self.clock_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ShowTime, 0.5)

    def stopShowTime(self):
        self.clock_event.cancel()
        if (ard_connected):
            ard.write(" ".encode())
            ard.flush()

    def ShowTime(self, dt):
        if (ard_connected):
            now = datetime.now()
            current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            ard.write(current_time.encode())
            ard.flush()

class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        updateClock = GUILayout()
        return updateClock
```

Comment: Thank you a ton, this definitely helped to clean it up. However, now instead of the time updating in real time, it shows multiple times once the button is back to 'normal' state. For example it displays: 18:06:3018:06:3118:06:32...

Comment: Make sure that the `ShowTime()` method is only mentioned in that one place (in the `startShowTime()` method).

Comment: Yea, that's the only place

Comment: Do you need to ad a newline at the end of each `ard.write()`?

Comment: Ok so the python code works, now it's the arduino code that needs some fixing. Thank you